# attaching an error to validator in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm using `Validator Facade` , here's the code

```
$req = Request::all();
$rules = [
    'name'=>'required|min:3|max:20'
];
$validator = Validator::make($req, $rules);

if(/*another problem*/){
    // ??
}      

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

I want to keep the errors that the Laravel's `Validator` make's It self and attach some others to them (If needed).
So for example If there was nothing wrong with the `name` input but my `if` statement found an error, the `Validator` would fail.

Comment: In this case, you should check the other condition after validator fails/passed (IMO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Validator MessageBag**

You can add the message to the `name` property of your form by adding it to the `Validator` `MessageBag`.

```
if(/*another problem*/) {
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('name', 'Something else does not check out!');

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

I would recommend doing this logic after you check if the formvalidation has failed, because just adding the message to the `MessageBag` will not set your validation as failed. Then you can manually return the redirect after one or more of these checks have been done to redirect to the form with errors and input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this validation

```
$messages = [
  'name.required' => 'Please enter name.',
  'naem.min' => 'The name must be at least 3 characters.',
  'name.max' => 'The name may not be greater than 20 characters.'
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, [
  'name'=>'required|min:3|max:20'
], $messages);
```

Comment: that's not what I need, consider checking something that's impossible for Laravel's Validator

Comment: that's another way, I want to do the laziest way, just manually checking something and attaching errors